# Obtener el valor de una fila en Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
<table class="table" id="table_fixed">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>ID_COMPANY</th>
                      <th>AP.PATERNO</th>
                      <th>AP.MATERNO</th>
                      <th>NOMBRES</th>                          
                      <th>ESTADO</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody id="tboby_con_com">
                    @foreach ($result as $element)
                    <tr>
                      <td>{{ $element->id }}</td>                    
                      <td>{{ $element->id_company }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $element->firstlastname }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $element->secondlastname }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $element->name }}</td>                          
                      <td><a href="#"  class="fixedbutton">{{ $element->state }}</a></td>

                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>                     
                </table>
```

lo que quiero es que al momento de dar clic al boton que tiene la clase "fixedbutton" me muestre el valor del boton (se muestra 0 o 1)

lo estoy haciendo con esto pero me muestra todo el codigo que se encuentra dentro de td, pero yo quiero solo el valor 0 o 1.

```
$('#table_fixed #tboby_con_com').on( 'click', '.fixedbutton', function (){
    var currow = $(this).closest('tr');
    var id = currow.find('td:eq(0)').html();
    var state = currow.find('td:eq(13)').html();
    alert(state);    
});
```

me muestra lo siguiente:

```
<a href="#"  class="fixedbutton">1</a>
```

y yo solo quiero que salga

```
1
```

Answer (score 4):

En lugar de `.html()` utiliza `.text()` asi:

```
var state = currow.find('td:eq(13)').text();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, salio !